# WebSphere Liberty + Intellij Idea - JSP reload on fly

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere-liberty

Can someone please answer, how to configure WebSphere Liberty under Intellij Idea to reload JSPs files by Ctrl + F10?
Currently classes are reloaded, but JSPs and resources not.
As far as I know, under Tomcat all is reloaded without extra configurations..

Now in my Idea Liberty server configuration are choosen following:

```
  1. Under Deployment Tab: WAR exploaded (or EAR - no matter)
  2. Under Server Tab: On frame deactivation and Update action: Update Classes And Resources
```

In server.xml are selected following features

```
<feature>webProfile-6.0</feature>
<feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
<feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
<feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
<feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>    
<feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
<feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
<feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
<feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
<feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
```

As server is used WebSphere Liberty Profile 7-8.5.5.7 version

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jay for pointing me into correct direction.

It turns out that IntelliJ Idea correctly updates resources both with JSPs in corresponding modules by Ctrl+F10.
Liberty Server actually caches JSPs in its own folder, and does not even goes back to check if JSP has changed. On my machine on Windows this folder was under following path:

```
 %YOUR_LIBERTY_SERVER_PATH%\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\138\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\%YOUR_EAR(WAR)_NAME%\jsp
```

My example Liberty Server path:

```
..\IBM\wlp-javaee7-8.5.5.7\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer
```

It looks like the path may differ. So just look for some JSP name which was already accessed, under following folder:

```
 %YOUR_LIBERTY_SERVER_PATH%\workarea
```

When found, remove 'jsp' folder, and enjoy =) Liberty goes back for fresh JSP.

If somebody knows, how to configure Liberty to always check for JSPs in corresponding module, please let me/us know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere Liberty, updating a JSP in an application does not trigger a server/application to refresh / reload similar to what servlet or class file does.  The reload of the JSP occurs internally in the JSP Engine only when that particular JSP file is requested.  It is then, it will check the timestamp of the JSP against the previously compiled .class file to see if they do not match and trigger a re-translate and re-compile.  That is part of the JSP request lifecycle, therefore there is no sense doing anything on the server until that JSP is requested.

Comment: Thanks Jay for reminding that, I agree with you.. Seems the problem is in resource reloading. Will dig in this direction. Meanwhile maybe any Idea why resources are not updated :)?

Comment: Strange, I see that JSP files are actually updated/refreshed by IDEA and datetime also. So why does JSP files are not recompiled when I am accessing them afterwards?